# How to determine if quantum mechanics is necessary to describe a given system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

The question might seem quite basic, however there is a lot of discussion on what to consider quantum and where there is enough just classical description.

As far as I know, if the density matrix $\rho$ of a discrete variable system at any point of its evolution is such that it can be diagonalized in an orthonormal basis, such system is classical.

On the other hand for a continuous variable system there is a simple criterion of the Wigner function negativity, i. e. if the Wigner function can become negative the system needs quantum description.

However it is not clear how these criteria relate with each other, moreover there is a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.2661.pdf), which shows that these criteria indicate different non-overlapping sets of states as requiring quantum description.

So is there a general criterion, which tells if a system can be actually described by classical mechanics?